# Autodocumentación API de Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, postman, swagger, markdown

Estoy tratando de **generar la documentación API** desde Laravel 5.8.* de forma automática, pero no veo la forma de hacerlo.

Mi intención es extraer el **markdown** o json (estilo OpenApi 3.0 o similares), con todo el código API autodocumentado, para poder revisarlo y mostrar lo que más me interese.

He probado con **Postman** e **Insomnia**. Postman crea una documentación online, publicada en su web, pero no es lo que quiero. Insomnia tiene un diseñador, pero no parece poder convertir la estructura de carpetas importada al formato final.

He visto ciertos paquetes de laravel que parecen generar la documentación, pero al final nunca logro conseguirlo. También probé con **Swagger**, pero no encontré lo que busco.

Alguien tiene idea sobre como poder hacerlo?

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os dejo una posible solución que a mí me ha dado la vida.

Tras muchas búsquedas os explico varias formas de **autogenerar la documentación API**.

Si usáis Laravel, tenéis el paquete Laravel Apidoc Generator  (**mpociot**):
https://github.com/mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator/

Con apenas 3 comandos puedes generar toda tu documentación API. Podéis encontrar vídeos en YouTube con ejemplos en vivo.

Sin embargo, **he optado por convertir el json** que me generaban aplicaciones como Postman o Insomnia a OpenApi y encontré **APIMATIC**, que sinceramente me ha sorprendido:
https://apimatic.io

Os podéis registrar y tener unos días de prueba.

Simplemente **importáis vuestro json** y genera toda la documentación API. Es más, genera tests en varios lenguajes y permite **exportar tu documentación** en distintos formatos, entre los cuales OpenApi 3.0 (YAML y json), lo cual te hace gran parte del trabajo. Os invito a que la probéis.

Simplemente, las variables que tenías en el json, las reemplaza y hay que adaptarlo, pero no tienes que hacer todo el trabajo desde cero.

Espero que os sea de utilidad.